# How do I show all "songs" that reference an "album" (for example)?

Tags: 8, entities

Suppose I have a content type (*Song*) which has a content reference field, referencing an *Album* node to which it belongs. When I view an album, I want to show a list of all songs which reference that album.
Can this be done?

I'd rather not use a taxonomy term. I've looked at the "Manage Display" screen for the *Album* content type, but I could not find any way to display the songs which reference it. I know that I can create a view which filters by album, but I want to display this information directly on the *Album* view screen, so when users click the album link, a list of all songs on that album will show up. Is this possible?

Comment: This can be done with Views (part of Drupal 8) and [EVA: Entity Views Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) The tutorial on the EVA page does something very similar. You can use your entity relation to relate the songs and albums within views.

Comment: No problem, nice self-answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for [this comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230366/how-do-i-show-all-songs-that-reference-an-album-for-example/230510#comment282517_230366) pointing me to the EVA module.  Here are the exact steps I had to take in Drupal 8, which is slightly different than Drupal 7.

## Steps for Drupal 8:

1. Make sure your reference field is already set up (e.g., the *Song* entity has a field referencing an *Album*)
2. Install and activate the [EVA module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)
3. Add a new view (*Manage > Structure > Views > Add View*)
4. Type in the view name, and in *View Settings*, set it to show *Content* of type *Recording* (i.e., the "child" entity).  No need to "Create a page" or "Create a block".
5. Under the *Displays* heading will be a label called *Master*.  Click the *Add* button just to the right of that.
6. Select "EVA", *not* "Entity Reference" (this is a difference from Drupal 7)
7. Under *Displays > Format*, I like to change "Unformatted list" to "Table".
8. Under *Display > Entity Content Settings*, change "Entity type" from "None" to "Content".
9. Change "Bundles" from "All" to "Album" (i.e., the "parent" entity)
10. Under *Advanced*, add a "Contextual filter".
11. Search for the field which links *Recording* to *Album* (i.e., the field in the child entity which references the parent), and select it, and click "Add and configure contextual filters".
12. Under "When the filter value is *not* available", select "Provide default value" and choose "Content ID from URL".
13. click "Apply".
14. If you know the ID of an album (parent entity), you can enter it in the parameter in the "Preview" section to make sure it is working as expected (you will need to pre-populate entities to test this).
15. Click "Save" under the "Display" section for the view.
16. A message should show up: "The view ___ has been saved."
17. Clear all caches (*Manage > Configuration > Development > Performance > Clear Cache > Clear All Caches*).
18. Navigate to a sample parent entity, and the child entities should show up on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the views list as you suggested and use the [viewsfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) module to embed it in your content.